Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation) for Phone Number OTP login
I've been trying to implement a phone number login page using Firebase Auth. But everytime I try logging in, I will always come across this error.
Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).
I have already enabled Phone authentication in Firebase and updated the plan to Blaze to make this work but to no avail.
Here's my component for reference
import { UserRound } from "lucide-react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
import "react-date-picker/dist/DatePicker.css";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import { sendSignInLinkToEmail, signInWithPhoneNumber, RecaptchaVerifier, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { app } from "@/src/lib/firebaseClient";
import { loginSuccess } from "@/store/authSlice";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer);

  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState("email");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
  const [confirmationResult, setConfirmationResult] = useState(null);
  const [isSendingOtp, setIsSendingOtp] = useState(false);

  const handleEmailLogin = async () => {
    try {
      if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, "recaptcha-container", { size: "invisible" });
      }

      const actionCodeSettings = {
        url: `${window.location.origin}/auth/verify?email=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`,
        handleCodeInApp: true,
      };

      if (email.trim() === "") {
        return alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
      }

      await sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings, window.recaptchaVerifier);
      alert("Email login link sent. Check your inbox.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending email link:", error);
    }
  };



  // Send OTP to the phone number
  const handlePhoneLogin = async () => {
    if (phoneNumber.trim() === "") {
      return alert("Please enter a valid phone number.");
    }

    setIsSendingOtp(true);

    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'send-code-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {}
    });

    try {
      const confirmation = await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, window.recaptchaVerifier)
      setConfirmationResult(confirmation);
      alert("OTP sent successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending OTP:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsSendingOtp(false);
    }
  };

  // Verify the OTP
  const verifyOtp = async () => {
    if (!otp || !confirmationResult) return;

    try {
      const result = await confirmationResult.confirm(otp);
      dispatch(loginSuccess(result.user));
      alert("OTP verified successfully, logged in!");
      router.push("/dashboard");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error verifying OTP:", error);
      alert("Invalid OTP. Please try again.");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      router.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, router]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        <Container>
          <div className="p-4 border rounded bg-white" style={{ maxWidth: "500px", margin: "0 auto" }}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-1">
              <h3 className="m-0 text-uppercase">Login</h3>
              <UserRound />
            </div>
            <p className="mb-5 mt-3">Hello, welcome back to your account!</p>

            {/* Email/Phone Toggle */}
            <div className="btn-group mb-5 w-100" role="group" aria-label="Email/Phone Toggle">
              <button
                type="button"
                className={`btn ${activeButton === "email" ? "btn-dark" : "btn-outline-dark"} w-50 py-3`}
                onClick={() => setActiveButton("email")}
              >
                Email
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className={`btn ${activeButton === "phone" ? "btn-dark" : "btn-outline-dark"} w-50 py-3`}
                onClick={() => setActiveButton("phone")}
              >
                Phone Number
              </button>
            </div>

            {/* Input Fields */}
            <div className="mb-3">
              {activeButton === "email" ? (
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter Email Address"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
              ) : (
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                  value={phoneNumber}
                  onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)}
                />
              )}
            </div>

            {/* Send OTP or Email Link */}
            <div className="d-grid">
              {activeButton === "email" ? (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-dark py-3"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F92A82", color: "white", borderColor: "#F92A82" }}
                  onClick={handleEmailLogin}
                >
                  Send Login Link
                </button>
              ) : (
                <button
                  id="send-code-button"
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-dark py-3"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F92A82", color: "white", borderColor: "#F92A82" }}
                  onClick={handlePhoneLogin}
                  disabled={isSendingOtp}
                >
                  {isSendingOtp ? "Sending OTP..." : "Send OTP"}
                </button>
              )}
            </div>

            {/* OTP Verification (Visible only after OTP is sent) */}
            {activeButton === "phone" && confirmationResult && (
              <div className="mt-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter OTP"
                  value={otp}
                  onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)}
                />
                <div className="d-grid mt-3">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-dark py-3"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#F92A82", color: "white", borderColor: "#F92A82" }}
                    onClick={verifyOtp}
                  >
                    Verify OTP
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>

      {/* Invisible reCAPTCHA */}
      <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
    </>
  );
}
export default LoginPage;

My client
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

export { app };

When I login using email, it works as expected. The only issue is with the phone number login
I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!
I tried putting a number with an area code but everytime I do so, i always get the admin-restricted-operation
